# $P(\limsup A_n)=1 $ if $\forall A \in \mathfrak{F}$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A \cap A_n) = \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\mathfrak{F} = (A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Prove that $P(\limsup A_n)=1$ if $\forall A \in \mathfrak{F}$ s.t. $P(A) > 0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A \cap A_n) = \infty$. (Side question 1 Is second Borel-Cantelli out because we don't know if the $A_n$'s are independent?)

Suppose $\forall A \in \mathfrak{F}$ s.t. $P(A) > 0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A \cap A_n) = \infty$, but $P(\limsup A_n)<1$. My prof gave us this convenient hint: Show $\exists M > 0$ s.t. $P(\bigcap_{j=M}^{\infty} A_j^{c}) > 0$.

$1 > P(\limsup A_n)$

$1 - P(\limsup A_n) > 0$

$P(\liminf A_n^{c}) > 0$

By definition of $\liminf A_n^{c}$, $\exists M > 0 $ s.t. $P(\bigcap_{j=M}^{\infty} A_j^{c}) > 0$. (Side questions 2 and 3 Isn't this =1? ...Wait, is that what we're trying to prove? Haha)

$\to 1 - P(\bigcup_{j=M}^{\infty} A_j) > 0$

$\to 1 > P(\bigcup_{j=M}^{\infty} A_j)$

Main question: Now I guess we have to come up with some A s.t.

$\to 1 > P(\bigcup_{j=M}^{\infty} A_j) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A \cap A_n)$, or is there something else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the series $\sum\limits_n P(A \cap A_n)$ converges for $A=\bigcap\limits_{n=M}^{\infty} A_n^{c}$.

Comment: I am considering $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A \cap A_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P((A \cap A_n))$. Are $(A \cap A_n)$'s pairwise disjoint? If that holds, I can come up with convergence.

Comment: Why would they? But $A\cap A_n=\varnothing$ for every $n$ large enough...

Comment: Wait. I think I got it. $A \cap A_n =  A_n \cap A_M^{c} \cap A_{M+1}^{c} \cap ... = \emptyset$ if $n \geq M$, and we don't have to worry about $n < M$ because our choice of A precisely makes $n \geq M$ ?