# Show that the series $\sum\limits_n P(A \cap A_n)$ converges for $A=\bigcap\limits_{n=M}^{\infty} A_n^{c}$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Show that the series $\sum\limits_n P(A \cap A_n)$ converges for $A=\bigcap\limits_{n=M}^{\infty} A_n^{c}$.

From here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878635/140308 (proof attempt is there too)

Sorry for the confusion. How does that show that the series converges? What about n=1,...,m-1? Does our choice of A mean that the index now starts at M? Why/why not? I guess I got the idea right. Just don't know how to say it exactly

Comment: Heee? Didn't you declare "Wait. I think I got it" over there?

Comment: @Did Edited. I am not sure how the series converges?

Comment: Hint: Every series whose every term after M is zero, converges.

Comment: Hnmm...so I split up the summation from 1 to m-1 and m to $\infty$ then? Yeah that's that. Thanks :)) now the question is answered. My last step in link by itself doesn't really prove the prop I think

Comment: And "I think I got it" =/= "I got it" :p